# How to find a field's belonging class

Tags: java

i.e.

```
Class TheClass{
    Date date;
}
```

Now with a `date` object I want to find whether the belonging class. What is the API to do so? so that

```
TheClass theClass = new TheClass();
Date date = theClass.getDate();

.......
String className = date.getBelongClassName(); // return TheClass or someway to return theClass
```

Comment: What if two classes having the same field called `date`, which class name you want ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ I thought java knows the reference if date refers to theClass.date

Comment: What do mean to say by *belonging class*? What I mean is that a single instance of a variable may be referenced in more than one class. So, which will be the belonging class then?

Comment: What's the specific use case?

Comment: Take a step back.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?  It sounds like you've taken a wrong turn long before you got here.

Comment: update the post, so it could be more clear to the goal

Comment: @Dave Newton use case is in aspects. Some general aspect places logic to all classes/method but now I have to place certain logic within specific classes if the object comes from the classes. I guess there is no easy way then

Comment: Specify the aspects to wrap only the classes you're interested in. Other options include marking the targeted classes with annotations/interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java object does not know all the references to it. Even the JVM doesn't have that information, which is why the garbage collector has to scan all references in the JVM to find unused objects.